# Problems with the pseudocode in CLRS

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I'm using CLRS as an introduction to algorithms. I am trying to implement the algorithm written in pseudocode in the book, in Python. However, i'm having problems because the book starts indexing from 1. This is how I implemented Merge Sort, but it doesn't work correctly:

```
def MergeSort(A, start, end):
    if(start < end):
        middle = math.floor((start + end)/2)
        MergeSort(A, start, middle)
        MergeSort(A, middle + 1, end)
        Merge(A, start, middle, end)

def Merge(A, start, middle, end):
    n1 = middle - start + 1
    n2 = end - middle
    L = [0] * n1
    R = [0] * n2
    for i in range(0, n1):
        L[i] = A[start + i - 1]
    for j in range(0, n2):
        R[j] = A[middle + j]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k in range(start, end):
        if(i >= n1):
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        elif(j >= n2):
             A[k] = L[i]
             i += 1
        elif(L[i] <= R[j]):
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
```

How should I convert from pseudocode to Python code without having these (off-by-one?) errors ?

Comment: Can't you simply subtract one from all their indexes?

Comment: But should I not do something with the end points of the range() functions as well? Because in the book the end points are also included in the loop, but in python they are not I think?

Comment: `start` is included, `end` is not. If you really just want to include `end`, simply change to `end+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Small error it is easy to over look this , indices in line of your merge function

**A[start + i - 1]**  should be **start + i**

Because you begin looping i from 0 and value of start can also get 0 which makes it start + i -1
and for the iteration where

**start == i == 0**

your index becomes **-1** which is actually the last element of your list in Python

and in final loop of your merge function The range should be

**for k in range(start, end+1)** because it has to be iterated from start up until end inclusive

This should run fine

```
import math
def MergeSort(A, start, end):
    if(start < end):
        middle = math.floor((start + end)/2)
        MergeSort(A, start, middle)
        MergeSort(A, middle + 1, end)
        Merge(A, start, middle, end)

def Merge(A, start, middle, end):
    n1 = middle - start + 1
    n2 = end - middle
    L = [0] * n1
    R = [0] * n2
    for i in range(0, n1):
        L[i] = A[start + i ]
    for j in range(0, n2):
        R[j] = A[middle + j+1]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k in range(start, end+1):
        if(i >= n1):
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
        elif(j >= n2):
             A[k] = L[i]
             i += 1
        elif(L[i] <= R[j]):
            A[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j += 1


arr=[4,8,5,6,9,8,1]
MergeSort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
print(arr)
```

Comment: I don't think it works, because it gives me [4, 8, 5, 6, 9] as output?

Comment: Okay found another error in your program the range in your final loop of your merge function should run from start till end inclusive